# Local Notification

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

Does Local Notification run on simulator?

Does local Notification run if i close(not minimize) the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and Yes. See : http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/local-push-notification-sample-code-os.html for an example