# Local Notification

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

When Notification receive os show an alert , is it possible to play sound instead of this alert?
and when notification receive os add a red circle on the top of app's icon , is it possible to disable it(means not show this red circle)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES,  we can play a sound

```
localNotification.soundName = @"music.caf";
```

don't set the applicationIconBadgeNumber,alertBody,alertAction property of the localNotification.

All the best.

Comment: and how to hide alert and red circle that os show when notification receive ?

Comment: i use this code but doesn't work   code:                              NSURL* musicFile1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"01" ofType:@"WAV"]]; 
          NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",musicFile1];
localNotification.soundName =str;

Comment: type of music file must be .caf

Comment: Thank you so much,just one problem hide red circle

Comment: there should be applicationIconBadgeNumber declared, don,t use it.comment and try. just now i checked its working fine.

Comment: can you help me , i want to know how to send localNotification

Comment: @Ghost rider: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924365/local-notification ,it has sample code too.

Comment: Thanks for source code and reply have you work on select video , when i try to select it start compressing